# MySQL JSON_REMOVE json array

Tags: mysql

I have channels table:

```
+----+-------------------+---------+
| id | sort              | bouquet |
+----+-------------------+---------+
|  1 | ["1","2","3","4"] | ["1"]   |
|  2 | ["4"]             | ["4"]   |
+----+-------------------+---------+
```

And need to remove "2" value from id 1 so i need to get this:

```
+----+-------------------+---------+
| id | sort              | bouquet |
+----+-------------------+---------+
|  1 | ["1","3","4"]     | ["1"]   |
+----+-------------------+---------+
```

I try using this query:

```
SELECT id, sort, bouquet, JSON_REMOVE(sort, '$."2"') FROM channels WHERE id=1;
```

But value is not removed if i use '$[2]' then value is removed but i need to remove by value not index...does anyone knows how to remove from json array specific value?

Comment: One option is to use [14.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i9Lcw5BTdTtsjgtPHohAMq/0).

Comment: thanks it works...but i use above solution because it is more user friendly to me...but your works as expected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  `id`,
  `sort`,
  `bouquet`,
  JSON_REMOVE(`sort`,
              JSON_UNQUOTE(
                JSON_SEARCH(`sort`, 'one', 2)
              ))
FROM `channels`
WHERE `id` = 1;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i9Lcw5BTdTtsjgtPHohAMq/3).

Comment: I am using this JSON_REMOVE to remove a value on a JSON_COLUMn but it seems to update the column value to null if it can't find the value. Actually, in the above case when if user search for `5` shouldn't it return the original value `["1","2","3","4"]`. Could you help with that??

Comment: @SarojShrestha: Try `... COALESCE(JSON_REMOVE(...), \`sort\`) ...`, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i9Lcw5BTdTtsjgtPHohAMq/14).

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
UPDATE channels SET `sort` = JSON_REMOVE(`sort`, '$[1]') WHERE `id` = 1
```

Working for me

Comment: Try `\`sort\` = ["1","4","3","2"]`.